# Populating listview on main activity from another activity

Tags: android, listview

I managed to pass string to main activity from another by intent and showing it as textView. Is there a similar logic to populate the listview on main?

```
private Button startQr;
private ListView validList;
private ArrayList<String> strArray;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
// private TextView textView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_caffe_list);

    validList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    startQr = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
    strArray = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.
    R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, strArray);
    validList.setAdapter(adapter);


    startQr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(SecondActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    //textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    //textView.setText(message);
```

The second class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getCode();
            finish();
        }
    });

}

public void getCode() {
    Intent intent = new Intent( Secondclass.this, First.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String array = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ARRAY, array);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

It worked for a single editText.

Comment: yes you can pass arraylist through intent and then populate your listview

Comment: please put code of both activities

Comment: I've put some explanation below. Second class is:

Answer (score 1):

If you want to populate the `ListView` from main, you should send an `Intent`
But this time you need to send as extra the `ArrayList<String>`.
So you need to implement the following code to send the Intent:

```
static final String EXTRA_ARRAY = "com.package.app.STRARRAY";
private ArrayList<String> strArray = new ArrayList<>();

Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Second.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ARRAY, strArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in order to receive the intent you need to implement the following code:

```
static final String EXTRA_ARRAY = "com.package.app.STRARRAY";
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<String> strArray = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_ARRAY);
```

Comment: I'll just elaborate a little bit what the application is suppose to do: Initiate qr scan on second activity ( I'm not sure is it better to use fragment or activity, I'm just a beginner ) Scooping the qr code string and inflating list view on the first activity. I'm just using this interim solution to get the data between activities in a simple way. This is what happened when I modified the code according to suggestions:

Comment: I modified Intent in second class: Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), First.class); New getActivity() method was created. I don't know what to put in the body and I suppose the Context should be String. With 'Second.class' instead of it, everything worked without crash but the list wasn't populated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `startActivity(i);` from your first `Activity` call `startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_CODE);`. This will help you listen to whatever the `Second Activity` has to say/return as a result.

The result will be received in the form of an `Intent`. You need to `@Override` `onActivityResult()` in your `First Activity`.

```
@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// Check which request we're responding to 
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
    // Make sure the request was successful 
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // The user picked a contact. 
        // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected. 

        // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below) 
    } 
} 
}
```

Check out [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) to know more about how to get result.

Now to set the Result, In the Second Activity you need to call `setResult()`.

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putString("data", "here goes you data");
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtras(data);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

calling `finish()` after `setResult()` send the data to the `Activity` from where it was called.

Hope it helps!